# About the definition of pullback (in diff. geom.)

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, inner-products, symmetric-functions

Consider $(d<\infty)$-dimensional ${ \Bbb R}$-vector spaces $V$ and $W$, and their dual spaces $V^*:=Hom(V,{\Bbb R})$ and $W^*:=Hom(W,{\Bbb R})$. Naturally, $V,W,V^*,W^*$ are all isomorphic. Now, the definition of a (linear) bijection $A:V\to W$ induces canonically a pullback operator $B:W^*\to V^*$ because $V^*$ and $W^*$ are functions on $V$ and $W$.
So far so good. My question is about from here on.

**My questions:**
The question is about the relation $B:=~^tA$ we enforce via the standard definition:
$$
(B(\alpha))(v):=\alpha(A(v)), \qquad v\in V, \alpha\in W^*.
$$

1. **Why** we couldn't define instead:
   $$
   (B(\alpha))(v):=(K(\alpha))(A(v)), \qquad K\in Aut(W^*),
   $$
   resulting in a more general relation $B:=~^tA\circ K$?

And by such a definition,

2. **what** are the consequences?

When we decide which vector in $V$ is which vector in $W$ ( *i.e.*, $A$ is not canonic, but a choice), it seems rational that we also could decide (simultaneously) which function in $W^*$ is which function in $V^*$ (*i.e.,* $B$ be a choice); of course by introducing a new isomorphism $K$.

**A discussion:**
So far I can see, such a definition alters the conventional invariance of scalar products $\alpha_{W^*}(w)=\alpha_{V^*}(v)$, to another relation $\alpha_{W^*}(w)=k_{K}\cdot\alpha_{V^*}(v)$ where $k_{K}\in {\Bbb R}$ depends on $K$. But is this make any trouble? Are there other changes?

Comment: What do you mean by $~^tA$? Is this the transpose of $A$ with respect to some chosen bases for $V$ and $W$? Or is it the adjoint of $A$ with respect to some chosen inner product on $V$ and $W$

Comment: $A$ is a linear map from $V$ to $W$. What is $A(u,v)$?

Comment: $^tA$ is the basis-free transpose of $A$. Given $A$, we have $\alpha(A(v)) =(^tA(\alpha)) (v)$ for all $\alpha\in W^*$ and $v\in V$. Thanks rumath and Ted Shifrin.